# any way to run intellij community build from altered source?

Tags: intellij-idea

I made changes to Intellij Community Edition (ce). I can compile and run those changes from within the IntelliJ editor. That launches a second instance of IntelliJ ce which is running from classes containing my changes. What I want to do is just run those changes without having to first load the source, compile and run from within IntelliJ.

Netbeans made this easy by just producing an executable as a result of the build. With Intellij, it's not at all clear what has to be done. I have tried the following-

using the Run configuration Intellij itself uses to run the altered classes- this includes setting the working directory , main class, vm options and classpath. Actually, this doesn't work for reasons unknown to me.

on someone's suggestion, running dist.gant in build. This blows up with very many errors which are not helpful (no class def found errors which indicate some confusion on Intellij's part  on classpaths somewhere)

Running WinLauncher.exe under bin gives the error message that it can't find VM options file (although it's in bin, (and also for good measure under bin/win with the other files which are co-located with vmoptions in the intellij directory structure for Intellij proper. )

ALl this is just harder than it should be. The solution is to provide an executable as a result of the build and place it in a predictable location.

Has anyone ever actually DONE what I am trying to do- make changes to the community source then use the resultant editor not as a project you're working with in IntelliJ  but as the Intellij editor you're working through?

FOLLOW UP
User60561 had the correct answer. Just to mop up the details, in artifacts, there is a compressed file (win.zip for Windows, mac.zip for Mac etc.). In order to run your snapshot, you have to unzip this archive (after which it will have the same name, minus the zip extension) then go into folder "bin". There you'll see two executables: idea.exe and idea64.exe, for 32 and  64 bit versions, respectively. Clicking on these runs your snapshot.

Adjusting contents of the files idea.exe.vmoptions and idea64.exe.vmoptions lets you set the VM parameters to suit yourself, typically people might want to give the VM more memory through the -Xmx value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems straightforward:

> To build the distribution archive of IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, execute build.xml Ant build script in the root directory of the source code. The results of the build execution can be found at out/artifacts.

https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community#building

So download ant, and run ant in the directory that you have it stored in. Make sure to use the commandline to launch ant in order to make sure everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Initially execute getPlugins.bat/sh, then:

1. Use update.bat/sh according to it's instructions

Or

1. Click on: Main Menu | Build | IntelliJ IDEA CE build
2. Copy content of intellij-community\out\deploy (lib, plugins folder) into existing IJ installation (sometimes it is better to delete existing folders if they contain older dependencies or when the installation was of Ultimate version)